# AutoLayout height based on subviews

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I've tried many solutions, but can't get UIScrollView to resize by it's subviews.

Error:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16e71240 V:[RouteView:0x16d76fd0]-(10)-[RouteView:0x16e6fbb0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16e71270 V:[RouteView:0x16e6fbb0(150)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16d78710 V:[RouteView:0x16e6fbb0]-(10)-[RouteView:0x16e702c0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16e71190 V:[RouteView:0x16e702c0(150)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16d78810 V:[RouteView:0x16e702c0]-(10)-[RouteView:0x16e70700]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16e713e0 V:[RouteView:0x16e70700(150)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16d78900 V:[RouteView:0x16e70700]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x16e6da80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16e71030 V:[UIView:0x16e6da80]-(10)-[RouteView:0x16d76fd0]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16d78810 V:[RouteView:0x16e702c0]-(10)-[RouteView:0x16e70700]>
```

My hierarchy:

```
Class UIView contains
--UIScrollView
  --mainViewOfScroller
  ----10-----------10
  ----|------------|
  ----UIView-10-UIView
  ----|------------|
  ----10-----------10
  ----|------------|
  ----UIView-10-UIView
  ………
```

What I Did:

*1. For all subviews of scroller(UIScrollView) I set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO*

*2. Set scroller height to the max by width and height of self( self is class UIView, it is main UIView)*

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scroller]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];
  [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scroller]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:views]];
```

*3. Set mainViewOfScroller to max by width( not by height to be resizable)*

```
[scroller addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|     [mainViewOfScroller(==scroller)]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
```

*4. Then I want to pin mainViewOfScroller's bottom to bottom of mainViewOfScroller.subviews.lastObject*

```
[scroller addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:mainViewOfScroller attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:mainViewOfScroller.subviews.lastObject attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using auto layout inside a scroll view like this you need to set it up so each view in there expands it's parent view. Scroll views work a little differently because of their contentSize. This was brought up on apple developer forums a bit ago, and I made a sample project demonstrating the constraints used. It's using a storyboard, but I think it can help you.

https://github.com/ketzusaka/ScrollingWithConstraints

The goal here is to have the first-level subviews be able to expand the scroll view. For example, if you have a two subviews in your scrollview, you want the top one to have a constraint to the left, top, and right of it's superview. The bottom one should have constraints to the left, bottom, and right of it's superview. Then they should be related to each other so they "stack" on top of each other. Lastly, you need to make sure each of them have a certain size to make them expand, may it be intrinsic content sizing or more constraints. I wouldn't have any of the subviews say their width is related to the scroll view; only have them be pinned to the edges and let the subviews drive the size of the scroll view.

Apple also has a technical document here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

And lastly, here's the apple dev forums post:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/917077#917077

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll examine your code and I'll try to get the differences. I'll reply you soon.

Comment: You doing your setup in IB, but I do it in the code, that's why I can't understand where I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a bit different, but the concept is the same. I think you're main problem is trying to size your scrollview subview to match the scrollview itself. Instead, the scrollview subview should be the size of its subviews. I noticed you didn't put any code about constraints for the subviews. Make sure those are sized properly and have constraints that will expand the first-level scrollview subview.

Comment: My main problem is "how to size mainViewOfScroller by it's last subview" and "how to size scroller by the height of mainViewOfScroller", I only started to teach auto layout and I don't know how to code it.

Comment: I made a project similar to what you're doing in your question. Hope it helps a bit more than the IB version: https://github.com/ketzusaka/ScrollviewWithProgrammaticConstraints

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Your code explains me some tips & tricks that I didn't know before. "Better to see once than 1000 times to hear"